# JavaFx Stylesheet in the same folder Not found

Tags: java, css, javafx, stylesheet

My Project TreeView is like this:

project
      - src
          -package
                 -javafx.java, style.css

I tried this  piece of code as well as just directly putting in style.css

```
    scene.getStylesheets().add("../src/package/style.css");
```

Comment: If it is in the same package, just "style.css" should suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try do it this way:

```
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
```